# Filtering specific frequency audio from a audio file using python

Tags: python, nlp

I have to separate a particular frequency audio(say 3700-8000Hz) from an existing or real time audio and then store the extracted audio data into a new audio file as output

Comment: Welcome to SO. You will more likely get an answer if you provide minimal reproducible example for other people to give a try and share what you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

I can think of two basic ways to do this:

1. Use a digital filter to simulate a bandpass filter with the desired frequencies. This might work in real-time; however, it is conceptually more difficult to do.
2. Use a Fourier transform (FFT) to convert the time signal into a frequency spectrum, blank out the undesired frequencies, and perform a reverse FFT to get back to the time domain. Depending on the window size of your FFT you need to work out what the exact values are that you want to keep.